# Ошибка при SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml

Добрый вечер) Подскажите пожалуйста:

Что это за ошибка такая :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in C:\xampp\htdocs\weather\index.php:124 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\weather\index.php(124): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('https://www.yr....') #1 {main} thrown
```

И где я проморгала этот момент. Не подскажете как править мой код? Голову уже какое время сижу ломаю:/
код:

```php
if (isset($_GET['city']))
{   
    $url =  'https://www.yr.no/place/'. $_GET['city'] .'/forecast.xml';
    $data = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($url));

    $city = $data->location->name;
    $dir = 'xml/'.$city.'.xml';

    // проверка, на то, что дата должна быть не в прошлом
    if (strtotime(date('d.m.Y', $_GET['date'])) < strtotime(date('d.m.Y')))
    {
        echo " !!наша дата корректна";
        // проверка, есть ли у нас уже такой файл?
        if(file_exists($dir))
        {
            echo " !!у нас уже есть такой файл";
            $src = file_get_contents($dir);
            $data = new SimpleXMLElement($src);
            // если файл есть, проверяем на актуальность
            $lastupdate = $data->meta->lastupdate;
            if(strtotime(date('d.m.Y', $lastupdate)) <  strtotime(date('d.m.Y')))
            {
                echo "  !!наш файл устарел, скачиваем и парсим";
                // если файл устарел, скачиваем его и парсим
                file_put_contents($dir, $url);
                $src = file_get_contents($dir);
                $data = new SimpleXMLElement($src);
                $str = $data->forecast->tabular->time;
                foreach ($data->forecast->tabular->time as $str) 
                {
                    if(strtotime($_GET["date"]) >= strtotime($str['from']) && strtotime($_GET['date']) <= strtotime($str['to']))
                    {
                        $forecast["Temperature:"] = (string) $str->temperature["value"];
                        $forecast["Precipitation:"] = (string) $str->precipitation["value"];
                        $windDirection = $str->windDirection["name"];
                        $forecast["Wind:"] = (string) $str->windSpeed["mps"] . " m/s from $windDirection";
                        $date = date ("d.m.Y H:i", strtotime($_GET['date']));
                        $city = $data->location->name;
                        $result = "OK";
                        break;
                    }
                    else  {
                        $result = "ERROR";
                        $error_message = "Not found";
                    }
                }
            }
            // если файл актуальный - парсим
            else {
                echo "  !!наш файл актуальный, парсим";
                $src = file_get_contents($dir);
                $data = new SimpleXMLElement($src);
                $str = $data->forecast->tabular->time;
                foreach ($data->forecast->tabular->time as $str) 
                {
                    if(strtotime($_GET["date"]) >= strtotime($str['from']) && strtotime($_GET['date']) <= strtotime($str['to']))
                    {
                        $forecast["Temperature:"] = (string) $str->temperature["value"];
                        $forecast["Precipitation:"] = (string) $str->precipitation["value"];
                        $windDirection = $str->windDirection["name"];
                        $forecast["Wind:"] = (string) $str->windSpeed["mps"] . " m/s from $windDirection";
                        $date = date ("d.m.Y H:i", strtotime($_GET['date']));
                        $city = $data->location->name;
                        $result = "OK";
                        break;
                    }
                    else  {
                        $result = "ERROR";
                        $error_message = "Not found";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // если у нас нет такого файла, скачиваем и парсим
        else {
            echo "  !!у нас нет такого файла, скачиваем и парсим";
            file_put_contents($dir, $url);
            $src = file_get_contents($dir);
            $data = new SimpleXMLElement($src);
            $str = $data->forecast->tabular->time;
            foreach ($data->forecast->tabular->time as $str) 
            {
                if(strtotime($_GET["date"]) >= strtotime($str['from']) && strtotime($_GET['date']) <= strtotime($str['to']))
                {
                    $forecast["Temperature:"] = (string) $str->temperature["value"];
                    $forecast["Precipitation:"] = (string) $str->precipitation["value"];
                    $windDirection = $str->windDirection["name"];
                    $forecast["Wind:"] = (string) $str->windSpeed["mps"] . " m/s from $windDirection";
                    $date = date ("d.m.Y H:i", strtotime($_GET['date']));
                    $city = $data->location->name;
                    $result = "OK";
                    break;
                }
                else  {
                    $result = "ERROR";
                    $error_message = "Not found";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else { 
        $result = "ERROR";
        $error_message = "Incorrect date or city";
    }
}
else {
    echo "else";
    $result = "";}
```

Comment: Ладно, я поняла ошибку 1. $src = file_get_contents('xml/'.($_GET['city'].'.xml', $src);

Comment: 1. Потому что каталога xml не существует? Потому что нет прав доступа на запись? Логи посмотреть не? Экстрасенсы в отпуске
2. Научитесь пользоваться переводчиком. "Строка не может быть разобрана как XML